# Simple authentication of REST get call with request interceptors of an Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angular-services, angular-http-interceptors

I want to pass in a username and password combination that is needed to make a REST call to an api.

**Controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//The service to put the interceptor configuration on (not on all $http method calls)
app.factory('getCallsApi', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        get: function(callback) {
            $http.get(/* REST URI */).success(function(data) {
                callback(data);
            });  
        }
    }
}]);

var Interceptor = function($q) {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            //TODO: Pass in username and password (hardcoded) to get through authentication

        },
        requestError: function(rejection) {

        },
        response: function(config) {
            //TODO: ADD Cross origin headers

        },
        responseError: function(rejection) {

        }
    }
}

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(Interceptor);
}]);

myApp.controller('appController', ['$scope','getCallsApi', function($scope, getCallsApi) {
  getCallsApi.get(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}]);
```

I am currently receiving two errors in the console. First is a 401 status for unauthorized access and an error about cross origin headers not found on the requested resource. I cannot put the X origin headers on the requested resource myself because I dont have rights to edit that response of the API.

Comment: if the server you are querying against doesn't allow cross origin, and you aren't in control of the server to add the headers, then ***the person who is*** in control of the server would need to do it for you.  There isn't a way to bypass this security feature.

Comment: Yeah, I know that it was a long shot to intercept the response and add the headers then. But anyway, how do I get past the 401 with the request interceptor for the service call?

Answer (score 0):

Not speaking for the cross origin issue, but here is how to add something to the request headers. In my case, I pass in a token that is stored in localstorage. We bind that value to an angular constant and inject it to the interceptor service:

```
.constant('AUTH_TOKEN', localStorage.getItem('myapp.authToken'))
```

And in your interceptor:

```
    var Interceptor = function ($q) {
        return {
            request: function (config) {

                if (AUTH_TOKEN) {
                    config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + AUTH_TOKEN;
                }
                return config;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am fairly new to Angular and I am not sure how to use this constant (with a combination of username and password pushed in) to authenticate my request to the api. I have tried making this constant - {'username': xxxx, 'password': xxxxx} but it does not work and I still get a 401.

Comment: The constant was just an example. You probably shouldnt be passing username and pw in the headers, rather as the body of a post request to login. What api are you trying to hit? Is it yours? Do you know whose is? Is there documentation?  I've never heard of an api that requires username and password as part of request headers. You should do some more research on how it works.

Comment: I know that its not a good idea passing in the username and password in the header but I am looking for a way to get through the authentication without popping a form to the user by providing a valid pair into the code so that it is used to authenticate every time a call is made. Its a private api and i am not the owner, although there might be documentation. Whenever I try to get some data its pops an alert dialog for username and password( do have a valid one).